# something wrong with my program's function python .extend()

Tags: python, function

while I was creating a function for a program in python, I encountered a problem. every time I run the program, after inputting what's needed I always get an Error saying: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'"
the program is:

```
def getDoubleList (generalPrompt, sentinel):
END="not end"
OUT= []
print(generalPrompt)
while END.upper() != sentinel.upper():
    IN=input(">")
    END=IN.upper()
    if IN.upper() != sentinel.upper():
        IN=list((IN).split(" "))                
        OUT=(OUT.extend(IN))
return OUT
#testing part (no editing below this point)
nums = getDoubleList("Enter a list of numbers:", "end")
print("Your numbers (sorted):")
for n in sorted(nums):
    print(n)
```

And when i run it i get the following:

```
Enter a list of numbers:
>2 3
>3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
[...]
        nums = getDoubleList("Enter a list of numbers:", "end")
      File "C:/Users/admin/Downloads/getDoubleDriver.py", line 12, in getDoubleList
        OUT=(OUT.extend(IN))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

however I don't have any nonetypes within my function. I don't know what went wrong in the function i tried to look for the problem but without

Answer (score 1):

`.extend` is **in-place** method, it does not return anything, it modifies your list.

see for example

```
>>> print [].extend([3])
None
```

or

```
>>> x = []
>>> print x
[]
>>> y = x.extend([4])
>>> print y
None
>>> print x
[4]
```

thus to solve the problem, simply change

```
OUT=(OUT.extend(IN))
```

to

```
OUT.extend(IN)
```

or to equivalent

```
OUT = OUT + IN
```