# Use Python dict to programmatically create Jupyter notebook with nbformat

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a Jupyter notebook with 3 markdown cells and 3 code cells in the following order

```
Markdown cell 1
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Markdown cell 2
project_id=53

Markdown cell 3
import mysql.connector
```

I am using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fperez/9716279) and the [`nbformat` documentation](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-nbformat.v4), but I have wrapped the line `nb['cells'] = [nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(text), nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code)]` inside a Python `for` loop.

Here is my code

```
import nbformat as nbf

d = {
"""Markdown cell 1""":
"""\
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
""",
"""Markdown cell 2""":
"""\
project_id=53""",
"""Markdown cell 3""":
"""\
import mysql.connector"""
}

nb = nbf.v4.new_notebook()

for k, v in d.items():
    nb['cells'] = [nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(k), nbf.v4.new_code_cell(v) ]

nbf.write(nb, "test.ipynb")
```

**Problem**

This creates the Jupyter notebook file. However, the notebook only contains the last Markdown cell (Markdown cell 3) and the last code cell (Code cell 3)

- here is the contents of the `"test.ipynb"` notebook that is created by the above script

  ```
  Markdown cell 3
  import mysql.connector
  ```
- here are the contents of the `"test.ipynb"` notebook that are missing

  ```
  Markdown cell 1
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  Markdown cell 2
  project_id=53
  ```

I think the `nb['cells']` command is overwriting the same cell repeatedly but I don't know how to work around this. After it creates the first cell, I do not know how to indicate that it should move to the next cell below.

**Question**

Is there a way to create *multiple* cells in a Jupyter notebook programmatically?

Versions

1. `python` = 3.6
2. `jupyter notebook` = 5.0.0
3. `nbformat==4.4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

1) You are overwriting the `cells` list in each iteration of your loop.

2) A cell is either markdown or code, it isn't clear why you have this dictionary with keys that appear to be markdown and values that appear to be code.  Are you making 6 cells total or 3?

If you want six cells--the dict key followed by the dict value--try this:

```
nb['cells'] = []
for k, v in d.items():
    nb['cells'].extend([nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(k), nbf.v4.new_code_cell(v) ])
```

This will add a markdown cell and a code cell in each iteration of the loop.

If you just want the code cells, then you can try this:

```
nb['cells'] = []
for v in d.values():
    nb['cells'].append(nbf.v4.new_code_cell(v))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to make 6 cells - 3 markdown and 3 code. With your first approach (this is the one I think I need), could you use `append` instead of `extend`?

Comment: Got the answer to `extend` vs `append` from [here](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/03/post-2/).

Comment: With this `nb['cells'] = nb['cells'].extend([nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(k), nbf.v4.new_code_cell(v) ])`, I got the error `NoneType object has no attribute extend`. After searching online, I had to use `nb['cells'].extend([nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(k), nbf.v4.new_code_cell(v) ])` (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112450/4057186))